# Crystal Reports using vb.net 2008 and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, report

I am busy with Crystal Reports, using vb.net 2008 with my SQL Server database, I'm seeing a problem here which I don't know how to solve. I've read somewhere about SQL Expression fields, they say they just appear under Field Explorer just like Formula Fields etc. But I cannot see it "SQL Expression Fields". Is there anyway I can add it to my Field explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Expression fields have to be created, just like formulas, they aren't "just there". You right-click on your Field Explorer "SQL Expression Fields" and choose "New". See this handy little [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crconsqlexpressions.htm) to give you more information and best practices. On the other hand, if you have more than one datasource in your report, SQL Expressions can not be used and you will not see the option in the Field Explorer.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Okay I understands u now Chris. I have more than one datasources. Thank U man

Comment: You're welcome! Please make sure to mark as answered if you are satisfied with the answer.